# How to use OpenWeatherMap API for historical data

Tags: openweathermap

I'm trying to use the OpenWeatherMap API to get historical data by city name, though the [Docs](http://openweathermap.org/history) do not specify how to pass an API key in such a call.

The example they have on the docs is:

`http://history.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/history/city?q=London,UK`

though without passing an API key I get a `401` error. I've seen in [other Stack posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33091948/using-openweathermap-api-gives-401-error) where people have succeeded to make calls by inserting the parameter `?&APPID=**api-key-here**`, though I've tried tens of permutations with no luck.

I'd like to use the following call so I can specify the time range.

`http://history.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/history/city?q={city ID},{country code}&type=hour&start={start}&end={end}`

Comment: I was asking same question to myself, what I find out is if you're using free version, you can only get data for current and 5 day / 3 hour forecast. Rest of the data is for paid users. I hope this helped

Answer (score 1):

OpenWeatherMap charges for use of the historical weather collection. If you're a free user, your API Key will not work for the paid content.

You can find more information about their rates here: https://openweathermap.org/price